# BIRT Report - group tables with different data

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am new to BIRT and I can't really figure out how Data Binding works. I need your help :)

I have two tables that need to be linked (Element(s) with Sub Element(s)) and create groups of tables depending on how many elements and Sub Elements I have.

There is an ID on each table to join them(BOBJECT_ID in Elements is equals with BOBJECT_ID in Sub Elements).

**Scenarios:**

- I can have 1 Element with 0 or N Sub Elements
- I can have N Elements with 0 or N Sub Elements each

To give more infos, here is an example:

[1 Element with 11 Sub Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5kL.png)

This is an example in case there is only one Element - The Element 1 is represented in the first table and the second table represents the Sub Elements of the Element 1.

In case there is another Element with Sub Elements, I need to create another 2 tables exactly like this one with the corresponding data.

If I have 10 Elements each one with 5 Sub Elements, I have to create 10 groups of the 2 tables with each Element and his 5 Sub Elements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what solution you decide you'll need tow tables or just one table.
two possiblities:

1. "Table in Table"

   - Create Dataset for outer data
   - Create Dataset for inner sub-data
   - Create one Table for outer data and add a second "Details Row"
   - Create second Table nested in the second "Details Row"
   - Filter this second Table to show only entries with outer row's ID
2. "Joined Dataset / Grouping on Table"

   - Create a Joined Dataset
   - Create one Table looping on that data
   - Add Grouping to that one Table
   - only keep your SubElements in the "Details Row"
   - (outer) Elements go to the "Group Header Row"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went for the second one with joined dataset and grouping on table. My only problem now is how to differentiate the two groups that have different number of columns and two different headers.

Comment: You'll have "Table Header Row" once per table, "Group Header Row" once per Group (your Element) and "Detail Row" once per SubElement. Just add this rows if not yet present and move your data to appropriate place.

Comment: thanks again for your answers. Actually, I needed to insert another Group Header and it works if you add another row by clicking on the Group Header. It's bizarre that it doesn't work form the menu by adding another header.